# Issue with Vuetify project build and production deployment

Tags: vue.js, npm, continuous-integration, vuetify.js, vite

I'm encountering a problem when building a basic Vuetify project using `npm create vuetify` with TypeScript, npm, and the Essentials option. After running `npm run dev`, the project runs successfully. However, when attempting to build the project for production using `npm run build`, the resulting dist/index.html file shows a blank screen, containing only the content from the ./index.html file.

I suspect I might be overlooking something fundamental. Is there an additional step required to properly build the project for production? Alternatively, if building the project for production isn't feasible, what steps should I take to deploy it on GitHub Pages?

Any assistance or insights into resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

My debugging steps and behavior

I made modifications to the ./index.html file, which resulted in changes in the ./dist/index.html file after running npm run build. Additionally, I made attempts to adjust the vite.config.mts file, although these changes did not seem to have a noticeable effect.

Furthermore, I verified that running npm run preview successfully displayed the built website, indicating that the build process itself is functioning correctly.

As an additional troubleshooting step, I set up a default build pipeline in GitHub Actions to see if there might be any production build optimizations included. However, the outcome remained consistent with building locally and opening the resulting files.

Comment: production files aren't meant to be opened directly in the browser.  they're meant to be served by an HTTP server.  host the production files on a server and (if server is configured correctly) they will work.  simple local server with python will work, e.g. `python3 -m http.server 8080 -d ./dist` or try hosted option like in [vite docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/static-deploy.html).

Comment: Or look at running nginx or apache or some other webserver to serve the built site.